# QAbstractItemModel over Network

Tags: qt, synchronization, qabstractitemmodel

I am in need of synchronizing models/forwarding models between different computers. The models can represent tables but also trees (entries with child items). The setup will be:

- Server providing a TCP Service (or other communication)

  - keep a list of models that need to be synchronized (`registerSourceModel()` in the like of proxy models)
  - provide the modellist with unique IDs to clients
  - provides `QDataStream` for packet serialization
- Client(s) providing a TCP Connection to the server

  - create `NetworkModel` instances based on modellist from server
  - forward / provide any `data()` queries to the model
  - forward / provide any `setData()` queries to the model
  - ... rest of typical model methods

There are two options of setting up the synchronization:

1. Have an `QAbstractItemModel` (may `QStandardItemModel`) with a complete cache (duplication of all data) on the client side, just updating on remote `dataChanged()`/`layoutChanged()` signals
2. Directly forward any requests over the network resulting in stub (Loading***) data entries until the real data has been fetched (`dataChanged()` signals) from the network

While option 1) will have quite the memory print, since we will have to duplicate any relevant model, it will most of the time have a very short response time, since synchronization can be done in background when needed.

Option 2) will have little to (almost) no memory usage, since everything will be queried directly. I am still not sure how this will actually **look&feel** when having big models to be visualized in a view. Think about an company catalogue (or list of amazon articles with some details) being required to be queried one by one (`data()` works on top of a single `QModelIndex`) over network.

As a result we probably will go with the first option.

The problems I encounter in both options are the synchronization/forwarding of a valid `QModelIndex`. These are always invalid on the remote computer. I did some research on the `QSortFilterProxyModel()` as this is kind of similar but within the same process space. This model keeps a identifying list for all indicies for mapping the "filtered" indicies.

Will this require myself to keep a identifying list of `QPersistantModelIndex()` on the server and a mapped list of IDs to my own `QModelIndex()` (with synchronization about these unique IDs of the list)?

Is there another option to "link" two models or even just put the whole model into some container and pipe that into my stream?

Comment: Have you checked if `QtRemoteObjects` already implements something like this?

Comment: @peppe I did actually check these, while quite interessting we still have to grasp the whole impact on using this

Comment: QtRemoteObjects does model forwarding, I don’t know about the approach or its limitations though.